# Show the fields $\mathbb{Q[\sqrt[3]{3}]}\cong\frac{\mathbb{Q[x]}}{\langle x^3-3\rangle}$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

show the fields
$$
\mathbb{Q[\sqrt[3]{3}]}\cong\frac{\mathbb{Q[x]}}{\langle x^3-3\rangle}
$$
where $\mathbb{Q[\sqrt[3]{3}]}=\{a+b\sqrt[3]{3}+c\sqrt[3]{9}:a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. I am having trouble to show the homomorphism between $\mathbb{Q[\sqrt[3]{3}]}$ and $\mathbb{Q[x]}$, and $\langle x^3-3\rangle$ is the kernel and the maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Q[x]}$. Additionally, I am also confused by what the form of $\mathbb{Q[x]}$ should be. As I only know it means polynomial over rational coefficients but I am thinking in this case it should look like this $\mathbb{Q[x]}=\{a+bx+cx^2:a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}\}$(which may be wrong.). I am a beginner to Abstract Algebra so a hint or explanations that are simple to understand is important to me. Thanks.

Comment: You're thinking correctly. You just have to map $\mathbf Q[X]$ to $\mathbf R$. You can choose arbitrarily the image of $X$, so you map it to $\sqrt[3]{3}$ and show the kernel is the ideal generated by $X^3-3$, whence an  injective homomorphism from the quotient onto the image in $\mathbf R$. Isn't it clear?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for your comment but the problem is I am not sure how to define this map since I have never done a similar question before.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea! Here are some hints to push you in the right direction.

First, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is the collection of *all* polynomials with rational coefficients. We allow polynomials of arbitrarily high degree.

Now let's try to use the first isomorphism theorem to attack this problem. We want to show

$$\left . \mathbb{Q}[x] \right / \langle x^3 - 3 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{3}]$$

So it suffices to find a surjective homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{3}]$ whose kernel is $\langle x^3 -3 \rangle$ (Do you see why? Here is where you'll use the first isomorphism theorem).

But when we write it like that, there's a natural choice of $f$ to try!

Consider the function $f$ which sends the rational numbers to the rational numbers, and with $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{3}$. Be careful! In this case $x$ is a member of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, it does *not* stand for an arbitrary element like it normally does when you see $f(x)$.

Do you see how to extend $f$ to a homomorphism on all of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$? You know what it does to elements of $\mathbb{Q}$, and you know what it does to the element $x$. But you also know that $f(ab) = f(a) f(b)$ and that $f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$. Since all polynomials can be built out of $x$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ using multiplication and addition, the rest of the homomorphism is determined by where we send $x$. This is another worthwhile exercise.

Finally, we have a map $f : \mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{3}]$ which is obviously surjective (why?). What is the kernel? Can you find some polynomial in $x$ which becomes $0$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{3}]$? What do you *want* the kernel to be?

---

I hope this helps ^_^